How to define $G$-equivariant module over a $G$-equivariant algebra
Let $k$ be a field and $G$ be a finite group. Furthermore, we assume the action of $G$ on $k$ is trivial.
In this case, a $G$-equivariant sheaf $V$ on $k$ is just a $k$-vector space $V$ with $G$-representation. Or equivalently, $V$ is a $k[G]$-module.
Let $A$ be an algebra over $k$ (for example $A$ be a quaternion algebra). I think we say $A$ is $G$-equivarant algebra if $A$ is a $k[G]$-module and the action satisfy $g\cdot(ab)=(g\cdot a)(g \cdot b)$. Am I correct?
If the above definition is correct, now let $A$ be a $G$-equivariant algebra. I want to know how to define $G$-equivariant module $M$ over the algebra $A$? I think first, we should require $M$ is a $k[G]$-module and at the same time it should be an $A$-module.
However, I am sure not sure, whether $A\to {Hom}_ {k}(M,M) $ or $A\to Hom_{k[G]}(M,M)$ gives the $A$-module structure of $M$.
Equivalently, I am not sure whether the following condition should hold $$ g\cdot (a\cdot m)=a \cdot (g\cdot m)$$ where $a\in A, g\in G. m\in M$.
Can you tell me which one is the correct definition of $G$-equivariant of $A$-module?

Your proposal $g\cdot(a\cdot m)=a\cdot(g\cdot m)$ looks strange because it doesn't use the action of $G$ on $A$. As far as I can see, the only reasonable definition that uses all of the available $G$-actions is $g\cdot(a\cdot m)=(g\cdot a)\cdot(g\cdot m)$, as suggested in the answers by Captain Lama and Qiaochu Yuan.

Of course there are several possible definitions, but in my opinion what makes the most sense is to start from the fact that the category of $G$-modules is monoidal, because $k[G]$ is a bi-algebra. Specifically, if $M$ and $N$ are $G$-modules, the $G$-module $M\otimes_G N$ is given by $g\cdot (m\otimes n) = (g\cdot m)\otimes (g\cdot n)$.
Now we can just unroll the theory: what you call a $G$-equivariant algebra is nothing but a monoid in this category, and a $G$-equivariant module over such an algebra should be a module over this monoid.
This means that if $A$ is a $G$-equivariant algebra, a $G$-equivariant module over $A$ should be a $G$-module $M$ equipped with a map $A\otimes_G M\to M$ satisfying the usual associativity and unit conditions. In practice this is an $A$-module such that
$$g\cdot (a\cdot m) = (g\cdot a)\cdot (g\cdot m).$$
Of course, as I said this is just one possible definition, but in my opinion it's the most logical one.

You just require every object to have a $G$-action and every map to be compatible with that $G$-action. It is actually more confusing to think about $k[G]$ here, in my opinion, so I don't recommend it. So the definition of an equivariant module $M$ over a $G$-ring $A$ is that it is a $G$-module which also has an $A$-module structure map
$$A \otimes_k M \to M$$
which is also $G$-equivariant; here the tensor product on the LHS is the tensor product of $G$-modules. This means the right condition is
$$\boxed{ g(am) = (ga)(gm) }.$$
As a sanity check, this condition makes $A$ a left $A$-module (and your condition does not).
A typical example here is that if $L/K$ is a finite Galois extension with Galois group $G$ then $L$ is a $G$-ring and any extension of scalars $V \otimes_K L$ is an equivariant module over $L$; this compatibility between the actions of $G$ and $L$ is referred to as "semilinearity" in this context but it is just equivariance.
You can also give a definition in terms of an algebra homomorphism $A \to \text{Hom}_k(M, M)$ (not $\text{Hom}_{k[G]}$) but you need to remember that $\text{Hom}_k(M, M)$ also has a $G$-action, by conjugation, and require the homomorphism to be $G$-equivariant, again.
